# Dafny: Using "forall" quantifiers with the "reads" or "modifies" clauses

Tags: arrays, algorithm, formal-verification, dafny

So I am trying to implement Dijkstra's single source shortest paths algorithm in Dafny based directly on the description of the algorithm in the CLRS algorithms book as part of an undergraduate project. As part of the implementation, I have defined a "Vertex" object with two fields representing the current length of shortest path from source and the predecessor vertex:

```
    class Vertex{
    var wfs : int ;   
    var pred: Vertex;
    }
```

As well as a "Graph" object that contains an array of "Vertex"-es:

```
    class Graph{
    var vertices: array<Vertex>;
    ....
```

I am trying to state some properties of the fields in each "Vertex" of the vertices array using a predicate in the "Graph" object:

```
    predicate vertexIsValid() 
    reads this;
    reads this.vertices;
     {
       vertices != null &&
       vertices.Length == size &&
       forall m :: 0 <= m < vertices.Length ==> vertices[m].wfs != 900000 && 
       vertices[m].pred != null
     }
```

To my understanding, the "reads" and "modifies" clauses in Dafny only work on one layer and I'd have to specify to Dafny that I would be reading each entry in the vertices array ( reads this.vertices[x] ) . I tried using a "forall" clause to do it:

```
   forall m :: 0 <= m < vertices.Length ==> reads this.vertices[m]
```

but this doesn't seem to be a feature in Dafny. Does anyone know if there is a way to use quantifiers with the "reads" clause or otherwise tell Dafny to read the fields in each entry of an array containing objects?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that most easily by using a `set` as a `reads` clause.

For your example, this additional `reads` clause on `vertexIsValid` worked for me:

```
reads set m | 0 <= m < vertices.Length :: vertices[m]
```

You can think of this `set` expression as saying "the set of all elements `vertices[m]` where `m` is in bounds".

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering my question last time. I have a follow-up question to this problem : I continued working on the code, and I ran into a similar issue, but with the _modifies_ clause instead. I tried using a set as a quantifier like with the _reads_ clause, but dafny still throws me a modifies clause error. I stripped the code down to a simple test to summarize the situation where I encountered the error  :(https://rise4fun.com/Dafny/ECHa) . Would you know why dafny is having trouble with it? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: Ahh, nevermind, just found out why. it seems that loops in dafny have to be annotated with the modifying clause as well since the context if the loop is separate from the context of the function as a whole. Sorry for botheru=ing you with this.